# Wordpress multiple category display with custom link

Tags: wordpress, categories

I am using `<?php the_category(); ?>` to display the categories of my post.

It was displaying but my problem is the permalink it produce.

the category link give this for example: `http://samplesite.com/category/funpage/`

what I want is to remove the category in the link and just produce: `http://samplesite.com/funpage/`

also, I am using [`custom post type UI`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) to create post.

anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_the_category()` function and get all categories for that post and display using loop.

```
<?php
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
?>
     <a href='url you want to pass add here '><?php  echo $category->name; ?></a>       
<?php 
}
?>
```